# rtsp streaming from desktop-server to my client

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp, tcp

I have a TCP server running on my desktop (used as a server). I want to use the RTSP streaming of a video from the server to the ijkmediaplayer client (display that on Android). **How can I achieve that?**

Have I to run an RTSP-server also for this on my desktop?

How to specify the path of the video-file in the server.
I have tried :

1)**rtsp://serverip/filepath_in_mydesktop** 
(this one doesn't give any error but I can't get any streaming observed in the android but evrything in the mediaplayer is working absolutely fine.
and 
2)**rtsp://serverIP:serverPort/filename** (the port, TCP server is using)
(this throws an error of can't resolve the path)

**Can you tell me how to specify the file name and how to achieve this on-demand rtsp transmission?**

Answer (score 0):

In linux absolute path eg: /media/sampleStream/streamfilename works for me.

Comment: so you specify the pathname rtsp://serverip/media/sampleStream/streamfilename in the rtspclient of the mediaplayer and have u run a rtspserver on your Linux machine?

Comment: from client (browser) I have *rtsp://serverIP:serverPort/filename* . I have server also running in the same machine.
I have put the code in github _https://github.com/dhananjayahs/TestStreamingMedia_ see if it helps.